# Using deep linking's target_url param in iOS app - what parameter to use in JS

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, deep-linking

I'm trying to implement deep linking in my iOS App.
As far as I understand, the way to pass info back to my iOS app is through the target_url parameter.

What I'm struggling to see is how to pass the target_url from my FB.ui call in JS. what property in the app request I'm sending should I use ?

When I post a feed on my wall the target url is the link I'm passing.

When trying to send an app request, if I send a 'link' property in the FB.ui call it doesn't seem to add anything to my target_url param. what I get is  `target_url="http://apps.facebook.com/:<App Namespace>"`

What property should I use in my requests to pass info through the target_url param I get in my iOS app ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check this link out, you will have to implement action links in your post request, don't replace your original link.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/02/21/improving-app-distribution-on-ios/